# VBA Run Macro with Button for Hidden Vba Code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cover sheet with a button the user clicks to generate pdfs. The other sheets are hidden/protected and unprotected by the code. It all works great.

What I would like to do is require a password to view/edit the Macro but allow the user to continue to run the code by clicking the button while the macro is locked.

How can I do this?

ps. I am a rookie at VBA

EDIT: Tools > VBAProject Properties > Protection 
Doesn't work cus it requires the password to run the macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools > VBAProject Properties > Protection

Password's at the bottom

Ensure that the sub you are trying to run with the button is a Public Sub so that excel can see it still:

```
Public Sub test()

End Sub
```

Comment: This requires the password to run the macro with the button

Comment: Edited to what I believe is the issue, will need more info to establish any other issues.

Comment: @Divi Glad to hear it, if this has resolved your issue could you please mark this as an answer? Thank you.